# Skeleton UI Reappears During React Hydration in SSR

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In our Next.js application, which utilizes server-side rendering (SSR), we implement a skeleton UI to enhance user experience during router navigation. However, we've encountered an issue where this skeleton UI is also displayed during the initial page load, which is not the intended behavior.

**Intended Use of Skeleton UI:**
The skeleton UI is designed to be shown during router navigations between pages, providing a smooth and seamless user experience as new content is being loaded.
It is not intended to be displayed during the initial page load, as this page is fully rendered server-side and should be displayed immediately to the user.

**Current Behavior:**
On router navigation, the skeleton UI functions as expected, showing only while new content is loaded.
However, during the initial load of the application, the skeleton UI is unexpectedly displayed. This occurs despite the page being fully rendered on the server.
After this unnecessary display of the skeleton UI, the client-side hydration process completes, and the already server-rendered content is shown, leading to a redundant and visually jarring experience.

**Impact:**
This behavior undermines the benefits of SSR by introducing an unnecessary skeleton UI display during initial load, causing a brief but noticeable flicker which detracts from the user experience and the perceived performance of the application.

Guidance or a fix is sought to prevent the skeleton UI from displaying during the initial load, while maintaining its functionality during router navigations. The goal is to achieve a seamless user experience, leveraging the full benefits of SSR without unnecessary UI elements during the initial page render.

I I haven't made any attempts to fix this issue yet because I'm not sure how to approach it. I'm reaching out for guidance on how to resolve this unexpected behavior of the skeleton UI appearing during the initial SSR page load, as this is beyond my current level of expertise with Next.js.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.